# regex matching for percentage type entry in textbox

Tags: regex

I want regex to be matched strictly to format "two digit, decimal and two digit" 
like 11.11 or 11 is  ok
but
1.11 or 111.1 or 111.11 is not valid

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Your examples do not match your description. `11` is not "two digit[s], decimal [point] and two digit[s]".

Answer (score 1):

**RegEx :**

```
^\d{2}(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

**Example :**

```
11.11
11
1.11 
111.1
111.11
```

Matches :

```
11.11
11
```

**Demo :**

http://regexr.com?33prh

Answer (score 1):

Given your examples, perhaps this is what you want:

```
^\d{2}(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string (or start of line, if multiline mode is on) (thanks @dr.kameleon for reminding me)
- `\d` - a digit
- `{2}` - twice
- `(?:` - start of non-capturing group

  - `\.\d{2}` - a literal period and two digits
- `)` - end of a group
- `?` - maybe
- `$` - end of string (or end of line, if multiline mode is on)

Meaning: two digits, and maybe a decimal point and another two digits

Don't forget to apply whatever escaping is neccessary in your regex flavor (`/delimiters/`, `doubled\\backslashes`...)

Comment: And thank *you* for reminding me to use a non-capturing group, instead of a capturing one... ;-)